# React app CSS not working after pushing to GitHub

Tags: css, reactjs, github

I built a basic notes keeping React application. I kept running it in the dev server using `npm start` command, and it worked fine and hence I pushed it to GitHub and hosted it on GitHub Pages. Now the app is running fine on the [GitHub Pages URL](https://karun31.github.io/notes-keeper/), however, if I try running it on dev server using `npm start` command, it runs a very basic HTML interface with all the CSS missing.

I expected the app to work just the same as it did before pushing to GitHub. I tried looking for any errors in the console or network tab in dev tools, however everything looked fine.